# How can I split up my XMonad config into multiple files?

Tags: xmonad

I'd assumed I'd need to add additional modules (files) to a cabal project file? But not too sure where I would find this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is burried somewhat in the FAQ: https://wiki.haskell.org/Xmonad/Config_archive#Modular_configs

Create a `lib` directory, and place your modules there, you can them import them into xmonad.hs like so:

```
import Path.To.Foo
```

which would corresponde to the module located here: `~/.xmonad/lib/Path/To/Foo.hs`

---

When using GHCi you will need to add a `.ghci` file with the following:
`:set -i:lib`